# Analysis Modes in SonarQube 5.2

Tags: sonarqube

I'm currently trying to make sense of the analysis mode changes in SonarQube 5.2.  The change of the full mode to `publish` is simple enough, but it's removal of `incremental` mode and addition of `issues` mode that is really throwing me.

Previously, it was suggested that incremental mode could be used to see issues in *just* those files which changed, while preview mode would analyze the entire project.  Is this still the case with issues mode?

My project is huge (1-3 hours to analyze from scratch) so having the ability to just analyze incrementally for things such as pre-commit checks or Github integration is pretty much a must to make the tool usable by our developers.

Any clarification that folks can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We decided to rename `preview` mode to `issues` mode since this is more clear: this is all about issues (no computation of duplication, coverage, differential measures, ...).

Having a real `preview` mode (ie a real publish analysis with no commit of results in the end) that would allow to check quality gates is planned for 5.4:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6763

We also removed the `incremental` mode that was very badly named. In fact it was 'just' a partial analysis. You can (nearly) achieve the same result by filtering input files using sonar.inclusions.
But we know that for pre commit analysis it can be interesting to automatically optimize the `issues` analysis by only executing sensors on changed files. That's why we will introduce something similar (but not exactly the same) in 5.3 that should be released by the end of December:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6931

Comment: Thanks, Julien.  So for clarity, if we absolutely need the old incremental functionality, we're best off staying at 5.1 and waiting for 5.3?

Comment: Or you can use 5.2 and manually limit scope of the analysis with sonar.inclusions=xxxx

Comment: So because you decided to rename a variable, now it just doesn't work from Eclipse. What to do please?

Comment: What about using SonarLint?